# How to get template type of base class

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

What in the C++ standard or C++ standard library will achieve what `get_base_template_arg<>` is doing in this example?

```
template <typename TResponse>
class request {};

class request1 : public request<int> {};

class mediator {
 public:
  template <typename TRequest, typename TResponse
     = get_base_template_arg<TRequest>::type>
  TResponse send(TRequest r) { /* ... */ }
};
```

such that I can do:

```
mediator m{};
request1 r{};
int x = m.send(r);
```

**EDIT:**
thank you to [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481267)'s answer; a complete solution may look like:

```
template <typename TResponse>
class request {
 public:
  using response_type = TResponse;
};

class request1 : public request<int> {};

class mediator {
 public:
  template<typename TRequest,
    typename TResponse = typename TRequest::response_type>

  TResponse send(const TRequest& r) { /* ... */ }
};


// usage:
mediator m{};
request1 r{};
auto x = m.send(r); // x is inferred `int`
```

Comment: Are you sure you want private inheritance for `request1`? And what about the missing semicolon at the end of `mediator` definition? Why not post **real code**?

Comment: Anyway, why don't you add a `using` declaration in class `request`?

Comment: Thank you! it should be public; edited

Comment: If you can't modify `request`, this is where you start using `auto` and `decltype`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is often useful to expose the template parameter as a typedef:

```
template <typename TResponse>
class request {
  public:
    using ResponseType = TResponse;
}
```

Then, to get the type you want from `TRequest`, you can just write `typename TRequest::ResponseType`; the member name will be found in the base class.

Comment: Can it be done that you don't need the typename? I tried using `ResponseType = typename TResponse;` but that's not helping.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica you can only use `typename` with a qualified name.