# How to conditionally get template type of multiple base class with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20, template-meta-programming

This is NOT a duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161321/how-to-get-template-type-of-base-class)

Consider the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Bases>
struct Overloads : public Bases... {};

template <typename T>
struct A {
  using AType = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct B {
  using BType = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct C {
  using CType = T;
};

template <typename OverloadsType>
struct Derived : public OverloadsType {
  
};

int main() {
    // OK
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename Derived<Overloads<A<int>, B<float>, C<char>>>::AType, int>);
    // OK
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename Derived<Overloads<A<int>, B<float>, C<char>>>::BType, float>);
    // OK
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename Derived<Overloads<A<int>, B<float>, C<char>>>::CType, char>);
    // ???
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename Derived<Overloads<B<float>, C<char>>>::AType, void>);
    
}
```

Demo: [Link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2SkYnyFV0tt7WsKe)

For the last line, I need to detect that `Derived<Overloads<B<float>, C<char>>>` is NOT derived from `A`, so I want `typename Derived<Overloads<B<float>, C<char>>>::AType` to be `void` or something (it fails to compile)

How can I do this?

Comment: Well, without unraveling all of this, anytime I hear "is (not) base of", I think of `std::is_base_of`, is this what you want?

Comment: "*(it fails to compile)*" - well yes, because there is no public alias called `AType` inside `Derived<Overloads<B<float>, C<char>>>`. And you can't really put it there. What if I create a `struct Z` that offers `ZType` alias? All of your `Derived`s would be required to know that there now exists a new type with an arbitrary alias? This seems like an odd design choice. You may find some luck testing for `std::is_base_of` or `std::derived_from` *before* you attempt to use the aliases. Would that work for you?

Comment: No, ```std::derived_from``` does not work, because ```A``` is also parametrized class, you cannot know it is derived from ```A<int>```, ```A<float>``` or whatever in advance

Comment: I think this might the case of missing the forest for a trees. Are you trying to determine if some particular class defines an inner type called `AType`, when all is said and done? If so, all of this stuff with all of these templates and derived classes is completely irrelevant, and this is a fairly boring SFINAE use case.

Comment: @frozenca: As far as C++ is concerned, `A<int>` and `A<float>` are two entirely distinct types with no relationship between them. They are as different from each other as `std::any` is from `std::fstream`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik My precise use case is: 1. Determine if Derived is derived from ```A<T>``` for some T. 2. If so, figure out that T. ```AType``` stuffs are just workaround.

Comment: Ah, I see what this is trying to do. Hmm... I think I have an idea...

Comment: ... nope, my idea did not pan out; I think that an explicit AType definition is pretty much the only way it can be done, I see no workarounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My precise use case is: 1. Determine if Derived is derived from `A<T>` for some `T`. 2. If so, figure out that `T`.

With C++20 concepts, this isn't too difficult. You need a function that takes `A<T>` as a parameter. There need not be a function definition; we're just using template argument deduction. It will never be called:

```
template<typename T>
T getDerivedFromAType(A<T> const&); //Not implemented, since we will never call it.
```

Any type `U` for which `getDerivedFromAType(u)` works will either be an `A<T>` itself or a type derived from `A<T>` (from a *single* `A<T>` of course). So we can build a concept out of it:

```
template<typename U>
concept IsDerivedFromA = requires(U u)
{
  getDerivedFromAType(u);
};
```

So long as nobody writes an overload of `getDerivedFromAType`, you're fine. This function ought to be in a `detail` namespace or have something else that lets people know that it is off-limits.

To get the actual `T` used by `A`... well, there's a reason why the function returned `T`. We simply need a `using` statement that calculates the return type of the function call:

```
template<IsDerivedFromA T>
using BaseAType = decltype(getDerivedFromAType(std::declval<T>()));
```

Notice that the template is guarded by our concept.

Comment: I tried a test code but it isn't working: https://wandbox.org/permlink/V4I4mqwt9Ml5eVX1 Could you give some more help?

Comment: It seems that ```getDerivedFromAType(A<T>&&)``` doesn't work for derived classes from ```A<T>```

Comment: @frozenca: It seems to [work on Clang](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nzcn8dn5r). Why did you use a `&&` instead of a `const&` like my example showed?

Comment: The exactly same code (https://wandbox.org/permlink/nhIYuOvww8Ygca4W) doesn't work in Clang, I think when inheritance depth become bigger than 1 the problem begins

Comment: @frozenca: No, [it works just fine when you stop using a `&&` for no reason.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hM5Ka53zn)

Comment: Oh, ```const&``` works! I thought ```std::declval``` casts to rvalue reference so I needed to change it

Comment: @frozenca: An xvalue is able to bind to a `const&`. It will *prefer* a `&&`, but in the absence of such, it will bind to a `const&`.

Comment: "Any type U for which getDerivedFromAType(u) works will either be one that is derived from A<T> or is convertible to an A<T>." What conversions are you thinking of? Implicit conversions happen after template argument deduction (so deduction would fail). That deduction works with derived classes is a special case, afaik.